# Get List of Names from "Everyone Except External Users" Group on SharePoint JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-online

I am trying to populate a SharePoint list with all people of a certain group that has the "Everyone Except External Users" set using JavaScript. The issue is that I do not know how to get the names for everyone included in that group. I currently bypassed this by using ...currentContext.get_web().get_siteUsers() to get everyone with site access, but this is also getting people that should not be included into the list as well.

**How do I get the list of names for a group with the "Everyone Except External Users" setting using JavaScript?**

Answer (score 0):

You can use `clientContext.get_web().get_siteGroups()` to get site groups and then filter your group by id to get all users from that group. Check [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/hh185012(v%3Doffice.14)) for details.

```
function retrieveAllUsersInGroup() {

    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
    var collGroup = clientContext.get_web().get_siteGroups();
    var oGroup = collGroup.getById(7);
    this.collUser = oGroup.get_users();
    clientContext.load(collUser);


    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}

function onQuerySucceeded() {

    var userInfo = '';

    var userEnumerator = collUser.getEnumerator();
    while (userEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oUser = userEnumerator.get_current();
        this.userInfo += '\nUser: ' + oUser.get_title() + 
            '\nID: ' + oUser.get_id() + 
            '\nEmail: ' + oUser.get_email() + 
            '\nLogin Name: ' + oUser.get_loginName();
    }

    alert(userInfo);
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Comment: This is actually the first thing I tried, the issue with this is that the "Everyone Except External Users" is actually counted as a single user. When I used this, the only thing I got back was the single entry that said "Everyone Except External Users" and no email, since none is associated.

Answer (score 0):

have you seen this thread? [MSDN Social post - REST API to get membership of Everyone except external users](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/24caa874-d233-47a1-8039-da965bbd6ddc/sharepoint-rest-api-to-fetch-everyone-except-external-users-and-all-users-membership-group?forum=sharepointdevelopment)
Its a bit old but describes the REST call quite well: you can use it to get all the group members and then iterate through your RoleAssigments as the original poster suggested and see which names are in both lists.